# How can I change this code as short as possible?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

Can I write this code as short as possible? I marked the start and end of the code that I want to change(It's in script, after the for loop). Maybe I should do that by for loop? Or maybe there is an easy way to do that.I just have no idea what to do. If you want I can explain the main question. Thanks for reading and helping.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Clicker+Script&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>
    <style>
        body {
            background-image: url('169240.jpg');
            background-size: cover;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        .p {
            transform: rotate(-90deg);
            -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
            -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
            position: absolute;
            color: white;
            font-size: 26px;
            margin-top: 32px;
            margin-left: -33px;
        }
    </style>

    <script >
        var header_div = document.createElement('div')
document.body.appendChild(header_div)
var p = document.createElement('p')
header_div.appendChild(p)
p.innerHTML = 'Meal Diary'
p.style.fontFamily = 'Clicker Script'
p.style.fontSize = '75px'
p.style.marginBlockEnd = '0'
p.style.marginBlockStart = '0'
p.style.marginLeft = innerWidth * 0.4 + 'px'
p.style.color = 'white'
header_div.style.height = '100px'
header_div.style.backgroundColor = '#8C7484'
header_div.style.alignItems = 'center'
header_div.style.paddingTop = '5px'
var main = document.createElement('div')
document.body.appendChild(main)
main.style.width = innerWidth * 0.6 + 'px'
main.style.height = window.screen.height * 0.6 + 'px'
main.style.backgroundColor = '#F2D8CE'
main.style.marginLeft = innerWidth / 5 + 'px'
main.style.marginTop = '35px'
main.style.border = '2px solid #8C7484'
var data = [
    {
        name: 'Breakfast',
        bgcolor: '#F5D7E2',
        headerbg: '#E0AC9F',
        food1: 'Boiled Egg',
        food1_img: 'egg.png',
        food1_calories: 78,
        food2: 'Greek Yogurt',
        food2_img: 'greek_yogurt.png',
        food2_calories: 100,
        food3: 'Oatmeal',
        food3_img: 'oatmeal.png',
        food3_calories: 120,
        food4: 'Chia Seed',
        food4_img: 'egg.png',
        food4_calories: 138,
        food5: 'Nuts',
        food5_img: 'egg.png',
        food5_calories: 172,
        food6: 'Fruit Salad',
        food6_img: 'egg.png',
        food6_calories: 124
    },
    {
        name: 'Lunch',
        bgcolor: '#EDCCE5',
        headerbg: '#8C7785'
    },
    {
        name: 'Snack',
        bgcolor: '#DDC3E0',
        headerbg: '#BF9BAF'
    },
    {
        name: 'Dinner',
        bgcolor: 'rgb(191 171 194 / 73%)',
        headerbg: '#A697A1'
    },
];


for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var element = document.createElement('div');
    element.className = 'card' + i;
    element.style.width = main.style.width
    element.style.height = '115.25px'
    element.style.backgroundColor = data[i].bgcolor;
    main.appendChild(element);
    var header_div1 = document.createElement('div')
    header_div1.style.width = '115.25px'
    header_div1.style.height = '50px'
    header_div1.style.backgroundColor = data[i].headerbg
    var content = data[i].name;
    header_div1.innerHTML = content
    header_div1.className = 'p';
    element.appendChild(header_div1)
    var meal_div = document.createElement('div')
    meal_div.className = 'meal_div' + i;
    meal_div.style.width = '200px'
    meal_div.style.height = '115.25px'
    meal_div.style.backgroundColor = 'pink'
    meal_div.style.marginLeft = '75.6%'
    meal_div.style.display = 'flex'
    meal_div.style.flexDirection = 'row'
    meal_div.style.flexWrap = 'wrap'
    element.appendChild(meal_div)
}
`start`
var meal_div0 = document.getElementsByClassName('meal_div0')
var foodimg0 = document.createElement('img')
foodimg0.src = data[0].food1_img
foodimg0.width = '40'
foodimg0.height = '57.6'
foodimg0.style.margin = '5px'
var foodimg1 = document.createElement('img')
foodimg1.src = data[0].food2_img
foodimg1.width = '50'
foodimg1.height = '57.6'
foodimg1.style.margin = '5px'
var foodimg2 = document.createElement('img')
foodimg2.src = data[0].food3_img
foodimg2.width = '50'
foodimg2.height = '57.6'
foodimg2.style.margin = '5px'
var foodimg3 = document.createElement('img')
foodimg3.src = data[0].food4_img
foodimg3.width = '50'
foodimg3.height = '57.6'
foodimg3.style.margin = '5px'
var foodimg4 = document.createElement('img')
foodimg4.src = data[0].food5_img
foodimg4.width = '50'
foodimg4.height = '57.6'
foodimg4.style.margin = '5px'
var foodimg5 = document.createElement('img')
foodimg5.src = data[0].food6_img
foodimg5.width = '50'
foodimg5.height = '57.6'
foodimg5.style.margin = '5px'
meal_div0[0].appendChild(foodimg0)
meal_div0[0].appendChild(foodimg1)
meal_div0[0].appendChild(foodimg2)
meal_div0[0].appendChild(foodimg3)
meal_div0[0].appendChild(foodimg4)
meal_div0[0].appendChild(foodimg5)


`end`


    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Did you try using one for loop and then add the common part inside that ?

Comment: where the css is repeating for each elements, you better use a class and add it once ...

Comment: How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create a little helper function that does the repetitive part, then call it for each item.

```js
function createFoodImg(src, w, h, margin) {
    var foodImg = document.createElement("img");
    foodImg.src = src;
    foodImg.width = w;
    foodImg.height = h;
    foodImg.style.margin = margin;
    return foodImg;
}
meal_div0[0].appendChild(createFoodImg(data[0].food1_img, "40", "57.6", "5px"))
meal_div0[0].appendChild(createFoodImg(data[0].food2_img, "50", "57.6", "5px"))
//repeat for the others
```